# Problem adding list from on Hashmap to another

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap

Issue adding a list from one hashmap's value to another's

Basically, I have 2 hashmaps (map1 and map2), both have the same keys(Integers from 0-500), but different values.  What I'm wanting to do is use the value of map1, which is a String, as the key and the value of map2, which is a List, as the value.  Adding map1 as the key is working, no problem, but when I try to add map2's value as map's value, it just returns as null.

This is for a homework project, where we are given 2 .csv files, one with labels and another with fake image file names, and have to be able to search by either image label or image file name.

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "null", "unlikely-arg-type" })
    public ImageLabelReader(String labelMappingFile, String imageMappingFile) throws IOException {
        Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        Map<Integer, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        BufferedReader labelIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(labelMappingFile));
        BufferedReader imageIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(imageMappingFile));
        String row;
        String[] rowArray;
        while ((row = labelIn.readLine()) != null) {
            rowArray = row.split(" ", 2);
            map1.put(Integer.parseInt(rowArray[0]), rowArray[1]);
            }
        labelIn.close();
        while ((row = imageIn.readLine()) != null) {
            rowArray = row.split(" ", 2);
            if(map2.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(rowArray[1]))) {
                List<String> tempList = map2.get(Integer.parseInt(rowArray[1]));
                tempList.add(rowArray[0]);
            } else {
                List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
                l.add(rowArray[0]);
                map2.put(Integer.parseInt(rowArray[1]), l);
            }
        }
        imageIn.close();
        List<String> t = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < map1.size(); i++) {
            t.clear();
            for(String s : map2.get(i)) {
                t.add(s);
                System.out.println(t);
            }

            map.put(map1.get(i), map2.get(i));

        }

        System.out.println(map.containsKey("burrito"));
        System.out.print(map2.get("burrito"));
    }
```

Output is "True null" when the output should be "True [list containing strings]"

Comment: You are calling `map.containsKey` but `map2.get`. Is that a typo? Did you mean to access the same Map? It should probably be `map.get("burrito")`

Comment: shouldn't you be doing `map.put(map1.get(i), t);` instead of `map.put(map1.get(i), map2.get(i));`

Comment: That is a mistake - I had completely glossed over that... and now I see that it works.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: map2.get("burrito") map2's key is integer. while "burrito" is a string

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing -

```
map.put(map1.get(i), map2.get(i));
```

with

```
map.put(map1.get(i), t);
```

And also -

```
System.out.print(map2.get("burrito"));
```

with

```
System.out.print(map.get("burrito"));
```

Also, you're trying to get map's value using a `String` while you said the key is of `int` type, please check that.